# The mathematical meaning of a zero gradient pressure boundary condition in the Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, navier-stokes, incompressible

I would like to solve the Navier-Stokes equations for the unsteady problem of the flow around a circular cylinder. I would like to understand how to write mathematically the boundary condition for the pressure on the surface of the cylinder (essentially the circle). The domain of the problem is shown in the image below with the cylinder having a diameter D and centered in the origin.

I usually solve this problem using the CFD solver OpenFOAM, therefore, I will describe the boundary conditions for this problem which are common among OpenFOAM users. At the inlet the velocity $u$ is $(1,0)$ and zero gradient pressure is imposed. On the sides the so-called slip condition is imposed for velocity and zero gradient is used for pressure, while on the outlet we have zero gradient for velocity and zero pressure. In OpenFOAM, zero gradient pressure is often used for the obstacles in the domain such as the cylinder in this case and a zero velocity is assumed. Whenever a zero gradient condition is mentioned, what is meant is zero gradient in the direction perpendicular to the flow (for example on the outlet only the $x$-derivative is equal to zero for the velocity components $U$ and $V$ that is $U_x = V_x = 0$).

For the case of the cylinder boundary, is it correct to assume that the scalar product between the pressure gradient $\nabla p = (p_x,p_y)$ and the normal vector at the boundary $\boldsymbol{n} = \frac{(x,y)}{0.5D}$ has to be zero, in other words:

$$
\nabla p \cdot \boldsymbol{n} = x p_x + y p_y = 0
$$

Is that the correct formulation of the pressure boundary condition ? and is there another physical condition for the pressure at the cylinder boundary ?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you assuming that the circle is centered at the origin?

Comment: Separately, though: Why do you think that this is the "correct" boundary condition? What is the physical situation you are trying to model?

Comment: I have updated the question in order to give more details about the problem, @WolfgangBangerth yes the cylinder is centered at the origin, as for the boundary condition, I just used what is typically used in OpenFOAM, the point now is that I am trying to formulate the problem in another solver using OpenFOAM settings that's why I need to understand how each condition is written mathematically. Thank you.

Comment: The formula you show looks correct to me. Though I have no idea what a zero (normal) gradient pressure would actually mean. It's not a boundary condition I've ever encountered, and one cannot impose boundary conditions on the pressure to begin with in the Navier-Stokes equations. It may be the boundary condition chosen for the pressure Schur complement in split schemes, though.

Comment: I agree with @WolfgangBangerth, all of the BCs I have seen try to enforce that fluid cannot go through the surface (flux through the circle inward is zero) and that the tangential velocity is zero, similar to wall boundary conditions usually used.  If you are using a vorticity formulation you would need the same conditions but changed to impact vorticity instead.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, ok then it might be that OpenFOAM uses these kind of conditions for the pressure because of the fact that it employs algorithms such as SIMPLE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMPLE_algorithm which uses the pressure Schur complement as you mentioned. But in general do you feel the need for imposing any pressure BC on the domain of this pb and what about the conditions for the velocity such as the slip conditions on the bottom and top sides ? Thank you very much.

Comment: @KyleMandli Thanks for your answer, so for this problem how would you write the condition "flux through the circle inward is zero" of  mathematically. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SaddamNYHijazi Well, the physically correct boundary condition on an obstacle is $v=0$. You cannot impose pressure boundary conditions (either the value of the pressure or its derivative) from a mathematical perspective because the pressure is in $L_2$.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thanks for your answer, are you saying that assuming a zero velocity in all components is not correct (i.e. $U=V=0$ ?

Comment: @SaddamNYHijazi No, the opposite, and as you suggest: The physically correct boundary condition is that all components of the velocity are zero.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, thanks for the answer. Actually I was trying to solve the problem using another technique based on the use of neural networks and I face the problem of getting almost identical solutions for all time instants which I thought could be caused from a wrong condition on the cylinder boundary. However, it seems that the conditions are physically correct.

Comment: OpenFOAM use the pressure correction method to solve the incompressible flow problem . The zero pressure gradient method means we don't need to correct and known velocity at the boundary since it has been known already. Please reference the book of Pantakar .